# Send event after controller has bean loaded

Tags: angularjs, events

I have two controllers, when user press the button to load SeconvView, the FirctCtrl sends event to the SecondCtrl via $rootScope.$broadcast.

```
 // FirstCtrl.js
 app.controller('FirstCtrl', ['$scope', function($rootScope, $scope) {
   // ...
   $scope.emitEvent = function(){
      console.log("Emitting event");
      $rootScope.$broadcast("EventName", "event data");
   }
}]);

// SecondCtrl.js
app.controller('SecondCtrl', ['$scope', function($rootScope, $scope) {
  console.log("Hola from SecondCtrl");
  $rootScope.$on("EventName", function(event, data){
    console.log(data);
  });
}]);
```

Log output:

```
Emitting event
Hola from SecondCtrl
```

So, the problem is that SecndCtrl can't catch the event. I think that this is because the events sends before SecondCtrl is loaded.
With little timeout i can solve this problem, but ... common, i must use timeout for this :/

```
     // FirstCtrl.js
     app.controller('FirstCtrl', ['$scope', function($rootScope, $scope) {
       // ...

        $scope.emitEvent = function(){
           $timeout(function() {
           console.log("Emitting event");
           $rootScope.$broadcast("EventName", "event data");
         },100);
        }

    }]);
```

Log output:

```
Hola from SecondCtrl
Emitting event
event data
```

Some better way to solve this ?

Comment: I think this is not proper place to use angular events. Why you want your first controller to pass event after user load the second view? Just to pass data? There are many ways to do it without events.

Comment: @djxak exactly, I want to pass data from FirstCtrl to SecondCtrl only to show the data that selected in first view. I see that Simon H recommends to use services.

Comment: Yes, the service is good here. Because all angular services are singletons you can inject your service in both controllers and set your data in one controller and read from second controller. Also you can use `$rootScope` to share data but this is not best practice.

Answer (score 1):

Passing data between controllers is one of the main uses of a service / factory instead

```
 // FirstCtrl.js
 app.controller('FirstCtrl', ['$scope', function(MyFactory, $scope) {
   // ...
   $scope.emitEvent = function(){
      console.log("Emitting event");
      MyFactory.storedvalue = "event data";
   }
}]);

// SecondCtrl.js
app.controller('SecondCtrl', ['$scope', function(MyFactory, $scope) {
  console.log("Hola from SecondCtrl");

    console.log(MyFactory.storedvalue);
  });
}]);
```